# Richfaces tree context menu

Tags: jsf, tree, richfaces

I'm trying to add context menu to one of my components which is actually rich:tree.

```
<rich:tree switchType="ajax" ... >

            <rich:contextMenu event="oncontextmenu" attached="true" submitMode="ajax" id="treeMenu">
                <rich:menuItem>
                    <h:commandLink action="action.deleteResource" value="Delete" />
                </rich:menuItem>
                <rich:menuItem>
                    <h:commandLink action="action.editResource" value="Edit" />
                </rich:menuItem>
            </rich:contextMenu>
        </rich:tree>
```

However I can't see it when I hit right mouse button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.... just put

```
<rich:contextMenu>
```

inside of

```
<rich:treeNode>
```